# Removing a list in a list of lists if a condition not satisfied

Tags: python, list, intersection

I have a list of lists. I want to remove lists if the lenght of intersection of values in the list with previous lists is more than one.

For example

```
A=[(1,2,3,4), (2,3,5,6),(1,7,8,9),(2,4,6,8)]
```

We need to keep first list because there is no previous list. We remove `(2,3,5,6)` as its intersection of previous list is `(2,3)` and its length is `2`. We keep `(1,7,8,9)` and remove `(2,4,6,8)` likewise.

At the end our list should become `B=[(1,2,3,4), (1,7,8,9)]`

Comment: I try to create a loop. I keep first list, remove second list as its length of intersection is more than one. Because I remove second list, now (1,7,8,9) becomes my second list. I compare it with existing previous lists which is (1,2,3,4). I keep (1,7,8,9). I compare (2,4,6,8) with (1,2,3,4) if it passes the test, then i compare it with (1,7,8,9).

Comment: To be clear: That is a list of tuples...

Comment: Ah the question is ambiguous. your comment clarifies it... I answered based on how I understood the question... I will try to fix it.

Comment: What about `[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7)]`?

Comment: @KellyBundy As length of intersection of each tuple with previous tuples is not more than one, we need to keep all tuples in your example. Ouss' and AboAmmar's code solve my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potentially more efficient solution, in case you have (and keep) many more but still short tuples. This checks pairs of numbers in the lists. Keep the current tuple `a` if none of its pairs occur in an already kept tuple.

```
from itertools import combinations

A = [(1,2,3,4), (2,3,5,6), (1,7,8,9), (2,4,6,8)]

B = []
B_pairs = set()
for a in A:
    pairs = set(map(frozenset, combinations(a, 2)))
    if not B_pairs & pairs:
        B.append(a)
        B_pairs |= pairs
print(B)
```

Some benchmark with Ouss's solution, since they brought that up:

```
With 5000 tuples, 2553 of which are kept:
  23 ms  Kelly
2853 ms  Ouss

With 5000 tuples, 2540 of which are kept:
  21 ms  Kelly
2776 ms  Ouss

With 5000 tuples, 2558 of which are kept:
  20 ms  Kelly
2685 ms  Ouss
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRRj9owDH7vr7CEbjQbQjCYNCH1JPq6hz3uYTqhtHVHRJtUSTrEtvvtzE4OCtzddrwUx/b3@YvtdAe/NXrxubPHY21NC8qj9cY0DlTbGeuhNG2htPTKaJckFdbwBZvmkK7FKgHIIYPvD/xn00llHZkOfSropDYWJCgNaw4EuPS3skuJ7hdqsiZXHKmcwEchRMhRNWjjz@DvIkjE418@lV2HukqlGM6egv9kMZocFn1vNeSx/q@9c6fyMyqevqOgW3oE8xMtuL5olPOO6jc1@C0Cm7B@QdUICFJpBKkr4iE5IV5pwnNYBkmkr2c7Srr0ZLMnkDN9PZAXbOUhgFkLZs0H7aM30b1GeUPLqhlI921Bsfy9qAXkOYcrYSfVIodaIlqHltwtlFssd@7KyY2MWcV11rP6PmTz28wr//38OUBhUe4uZAU7XkwQSHk3jS0YN9QJdd/UqmmwSt5KOdCNYB3mj0bCm0BIDNyUHIxuDrdIsEeLYaLvYQ7J/7hKo73SPSYvjTq3v0PpeXpzwtyHcKmo/1wHzUbf@Ol0ejX@YcW9alH5035HK3osDTG/AdHjZNs1mCRr3nHf0/80HqUU9wPT@WwmJrAUIgzFhpsbHZ/I8ZB0loSlp8cCsuy0eBNoUJ8dtOnJTf5CxDt4jXj5D2JmDq9NYK/H35Tfwm8mXItHCGBuEg/OFTzyqO@3qtyCpP7ssPOrsTgvXt3rkjlC/CSoGHrE10dlxltMG9kWlVyFlKA07lM2H56nWNj4bllB62AMd5AGjPcwxwVlcOp0s9Gyxc1GXGgRx@Nf)):

```
from itertools import combinations

def Kelly(A):
  B = []
  B_pairs = set()
  for a in A:
    pairs = set(map(frozenset, combinations(a, 2)))
    if not B_pairs & pairs:
        B.append(a)
        B_pairs |= pairs
  return B

def Ouss(A):
  B=[]

  # iterate over sublists a of the list A
  for a in A:
    # define and reset the intersections counter
    intersections=0
    # iterate of sublists b of B
    for b in B:
        # reset the intersections counter
        intersections=0
        # iterate over the numbers num of sublist a
        for num in a:
            # perform checks
            if num in b:
                intersections+=1
            if intersections>1:
                break
        # break the iteration over sublists b if check fulfilled
        if intersections>1:
            break
    # Append a to the subset B only if intersection were not > 1 
    if intersections>1:
        continue
    B.append(a)
    # repeat
  #B now contains the result...
  return B

from timeit import timeit
from random import sample

A = [tuple(sample(range(100), 4)) for _ in range(500)]
print(Kelly(A) == Ouss(A), len(Kelly(A)))

for _ in range(3):
    A = [tuple(sample(range(400), 4)) for _ in range(5000)]
    print(f'With {len(A)} tuples, {len(Kelly(A))} of which are kept:')
    for func in Kelly, Ouss:
        time = timeit(lambda: func(A), number=1)
        print('%4d ms ' % (time * 1e3), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Nice benchmark code. I learned a lot today. Thanks. Would it make sense to add more repeats and more iterations like repeats=5, and iterations=1000 then get the average and std of the times?

Comment: @Ouss I usually do something like that, but in this case I don't see the point, as our solutions aren't close. So I kept it simple.

Comment: I did some benchmarking using timeit on my machine but for the case of A=[itertools.combinations(range(x),4)] for x=16, and that gave me the initial impression that my code is faster. There is a big discrepancy between my result and the result in your benchmarking code and I am trying to understand what I did wrong. Now testing for larger x... As I said I learned a lot. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Ouss That code doesn't work (your A is a list with a single element, an iterator). But if I fix it like I think you meant, then that produces a list of 1820 tuples, of which only 15 are kept. So very few are kept, and your solution doesn't have much to check. That's exactly why my answer says "and keep [many]". In my benchmark, my lists have 5000 tuples, of which about 4300 are kept. Or rather they were. My intention was to keep about half and I thought I did, apparently I messed that up. Changed now as I had intended it, see the updated benchmark results.

Comment: it was indeed the length of the list of tuples. I think in my solution we are talking about an O(n^2) and in yours it is much better... I am not sure... but it seems like O(log(n))... so no question there... your solution is much more efficient with growing n... not to mention prettier!

Comment: @Ouss Mine's not O(log n) but O(n). Have to at least look at everything :-)

Comment: Could you explain the use of "frozenset" there? is it just for protection or is there another reason to use it?

Comment: @Ouss You mean why I make them frozenset instead of set? Because I collect them in a set, for which they must be hashable. Frozensets are, sets aren't. (I.e. you can have a set of frozensets, but not a set of sets.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
A=[(1,2,3,4),(2,3,5,6),(1,7,8,9),(2,4,6,8)]
B=[]

# iterate over sublists a of the list A
for a in A:
    # define and reset the intersections counter
    intersections=0
    # iterate of sublists b of B
    for b in B:
        # reset the intersections counter
        intersections=0
        # iterate over the numbers num of sublist a
        for num in a:
            # perform checks
            if num in b:
                intersections+=1
            if intersections>1:
                break
        # break the iteration over sublists b if check fulfilled
        if intersections>1:
            break
    # Append a to the subset B only if intersection were not > 1 
    if intersections>1:
        continue
    B.append(a)
    # repeat
#B now contains the result...
print(B)
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy if A is equal to: 
`x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] 
import itertools 
A=itertools.combinations(x,4)
A=list(A)`

Comment: I read your comment on the question. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: [(1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 8, 9, 10),
 (1, 11, 12, 13),
 (1, 14, 15, 16),
 (2, 5, 8, 11),
 (2, 6, 9, 12),
 (2, 7, 10, 13),
 (3, 5, 9, 13),
 (3, 6, 8, 14),
 (3, 7, 11, 15),
 (3, 10, 12, 16),
 (4, 5, 10, 14),
 (4, 6, 11, 16),
 (4, 7, 8, 12)]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct implementation:

```
A = [(1,2,3,4), (2,3,5,6), (1,7,8,9), (2,4,6,8)]

B = []
intersect = 0
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        intersect = 0
        for num in b:
            if num in a:
                intersect += 1
        if intersect > 1:
            break
    if intersect < 2:
        B.append(a)
```

which gives:

```
B = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this piece of code should do what you are looking for

```py
A=[(1,2,3,4), (2,3,5,6),(1,7,8,9),(2,4,6,8)]

B = []

precedent = []
for list_ in A:
    intersection = 0

    for num in list_:
        if num in precedent:
            intersection += 1

    if intersection < 1:
        B.append(list_)

    precedent = list_
```

Comment: This is not correct, it compares current list with last list, not with all previous ones. Put `(1,7,8,9)` at second place and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one way you could try.

```
def intersection_length(lst1, lst2):
    intersection_list = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return len(intersection_list)

def filter_lists(lists):
    filtered_lists = []
    filtered_lists.append(lists[0])
    del lists[0]

    for list_item in lists:
        is_ok = True
        for prev_list in filtered_lists:
            if intersection_length(list_item, prev_list) > 1:
                is_ok = False
                continue
        if is_ok:
            filtered_lists.append(list_item)
    return filtered_lists

def main():
    filtered = filter_lists(
        [(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 7, 8, 9), (2, 4, 6, 8)]
    )
    print(filtered)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```